# Enlarge button before click in Android

Tags: android, button

I am a beginner in android, I have a problem with my custom button.

I am trying to do some special effect like this [fancy button](http://www.buildinternet.com/live/elasticthumbs/).

Which method I should use in this function?

I have tried gesture, onTouch, onScroll, Selector to create custom button and done a lot of research on the internet but still fail to make it work.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Enlarging the button or detecting the touch? I'm assuming that the button gets bigger as soon as the finger is touching it?

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is set an onTouchListener.

Then on ACTION_DOWN, I do some sort of animation

on ACTION_UP / ACTION_CANCEL, I do the appropriate reaction.

In this case, ACTION_DOWN would cause an enlarge and the other 2 ACTIONs would cause the button to size back down!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Most common use;

```
Button bt....;
bt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {do stuff...}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

onLongClick()
From View.OnLongClickListener. This is called when the user either touches and holds the item (when in touch mode), or focuses upon the item with the navigation-keys or trackball and presses and holds the suitable "enter" key or presses and holds down on the trackball (for one second).

Comment: I'd expect onTouch to work better for this unless you expect to wait a few seconds for the button to enlarge.